# Orientability and volume form

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I was wondering if there is an easy argument that manifolds that are orientable always have a volume form and vice versa?

So I am not looking for a full proof of this, but rather a good argument how the normal vector field and the volume form relate to each other.

Especially, this should be simpler in dimension $2$ and I even got an idea how to construct the volume form, i.e. if $n$ is a normal field then

$$\omega( \xi, \eta) := \langle  n , \xi \times  \eta \rangle$$ defines a volume form.

Now the question would be, how does a volume form $\omega$ define a normal vector field?

Comment: are you talking about manifolds with boundary or hypersurfaces? Otherwise, which normal are you talking about? An (abstract) manifold well may carry an orientation, but there is no normal involved.

Comment: @Thomas: I assume he's thinking about the case of a codimension 1 hypersurface in Euclidean space. Then a normal field to the surface defines a volume form.

Comment: You can define the volume form by picking a Riemannian metric and choosing $\omega(e_1, \dots, e_n) = 1$ for a positive orthonormal basis. (This is usually called the Riemannian volume form.) Conversely if you have a volume form, you can just say that $v_1, \dots, v_n$ is positive whenever $\omega(v_1, \dots, v_n) > 0$.